# How to filter a data/field base on a many2one?

Tags: xml, filter, openerp-7, many-to-one

Does any one can help how to solve this issue: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**? Here is what i did:

I made a module that inhereit on sale, crm, and account. On class **crm_lead** i add some changes:

```
def _get_available_product(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    vals = {}
    pr_id = []
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        id = rec.id 
        product_list = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr,uid,[('product_state','=','available')]) 
        pr_id = [product.id if product.id else False for product in self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr,uid,product_list,context=context)] 
        vals[id] = {'product_ids':pr_id}
    return vals

def _defaults_product(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    product_list = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr,uid,[('product_state','=','available')])         
    pr_id = [product.id if product.id else False for product in self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr,uid,product_list,context=context)] 
    value = {"value":{'product_ids':pr_id}}
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tVALUE %s"%(str(value)))
    return value 

_columns = {
 'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product','Product'),
 'product_ids' : fields.function(_get_available_product, type='many2many', relation='product.product', method=True, store=False, multi='compute_available_product', string='Available Product'),
} 

_defaults = {
      'product_ids' : _defaults_product,
}
```

On **crm_lead_view.xml**

```
 <group>
     <field name="product_ids" nolabel="1" widget="many2many" invisible="1"
 </group>
 <group>
    <group>
       <field name="product_id" required="1" domain="[('id','in',product_ids[0][2])]"/>
  ....
```

and when i try to create a Lead, the client error pop up just like above. My aim actually is that if i create a lead, i want to filter the product_id so that the only shown are those products w/c product_state is 'available'.

**Any help is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

your domain filter is wrong way to define in your xml view file

Just we should set the filter of the product field in below way

```
 <group>
    <group>
       <field name="product_id" required="1" domain="[('product_state','=','available')]"/>
 </group>
</group>
```

hear I show your above Question and  I have figure out the few things 
which you are totally going in wrong way to implement the code.
No thing else you just make a code more complex.

1.No need to create a new function filed for generate the product id which are generate  and give the product which are in available.

2.No need to create a separate field to add into the xml view file.

3.Added domain filter on product in view xml file is wrong way to defined

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: The problem with that case is that 'product_state' is not define on class 'crm.lead' rather it is define on 'product.product' class.

Comment: yes definitely product_state is the part of product but not the part of crm.lead so that in this case we have to set the product state you have to add in our product object